# Java: Display float with precision of 30

Tags: java, double, arbitrary-precision

I'm trying to calculate PI with some algorithms, but the main thing is to display it with precision of 30. I tried to output a string with `format` etc. But it seems that maximum precision of `double` is 15. Is there any class or some method to help me with this ?

I've already tried:

```
public class Challenge6PI {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.format( "%.30f",
                Math.log(Math.pow(640320, 3) + 744) / Math.sqrt(163));
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, what are you doing with your `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: @fge Sorry it's remnant what I tried earlier.

Comment: You can try an alternative library, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

While the JDK has `BigDecimal`, unfortunately you have no `.sqrt()` on it.

Which means your best bet is to use [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java):

```
final Apfloat f1 = new Apfloat(640320);
final Apfloat f2 = ApfloatMath.pow(f1, 3L);
final Apfloat f3 = f2.add(new Apfloat(744));
final Apfloat f4 = ApfloatMath.sqrt(new Apfloat(163), 1000L);
final Apfloat ret = ApfloatMath.log(f3.divide(f4));

System.out.println(ApfloatMath.round(ret, 30L, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));
```

You have a shorter way for pi, though ;)

```
System.out.println(ApfloatMath.pi(30L));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try with `apfloat`, but I've also tried with `BigDecimal` which gave me theoretically nearly exact PI number with precision of 30. But some numbers are not equivalent when I compared it with http://3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592.com/index3141.html , what I've got is `3.141592652589793238462643383529`, which is strange because most of numbers are correct and some in the middle differ.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the BigDecimal class! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess Float does not supports that much precision. You may use BigDecimal for that.

Answer (score 0):

double doesn't have that much precision. Have a look at how the [double type is implemented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).  For arbitrary precision have a look at [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

For example:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(22.0/7.0);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(30);
System.out.println(df.format(bd));
```

Comment: Do NOT build a `BigDecimal` from doubles! You will lose precision before you even _build_ it

Comment: Good point fge, thanks. Luckily 22.0/7.0 is a poor approximation of pi.